# Agreement between the verb "mean(s)" and a tricky subject "museum-quality materials"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> Museum-quality materials **mean** your document won't discolor.

or

> Museum-quality materials **means** your document won't discolor.

I am having some difficulty in determining which version of "mean" to use here.

While "materials" would suggest that we use the verb "mean", I have some doubts.

Is the concept of "Museum-quality materials" a singular concept, justifying the usage of "means"?

Perhaps there is an implied "The usage of" before "Museum-quality materials" also suggesting the usage of "means".

This one has me stumped!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're trying to say is

> *(Using) museum-quality materials* **means** your document won't discolor.

Go with `means`.

Using `mean` would imply `museum-quality materials` literally mean `your document won't discolor`, which can't be what you're saying.

This sentence is informal. If you wish to be grammatically correct, don't drop the 'using'.

Answer (score 2):

There is a phenomenon called "attraction", where words not in the line of grammar, so to speak, pull at our minds and confuse us. Maybe the singular "museum" is subconsciously haunting you? If "High-quality" materials do not cause you to have the same doubts about the plural "mean", this might be it.

I would use the plural myself, but "materials" is one of those tricksy words that is in practice rather intermediate between singular and plural. It is often treated as a collective noun, rather as if it were interchangeable with "stuff". So it could probably be argued the other way.

Comment: As in 'Beanz meanz whatever'. I think this massification (_not_ treatment as a collective noun like 'collection' in this case) is stretching things a little here. I'd use the less transposed 'The use of museum-quality materials ensures your document won't discolor.'

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *museum quality materials* ought either to be in inverted commas, or in italics.

The sentence provides the meaning of that expression, and the expression is singular.

*Twenty-two yards* means the length of a cricket pitch. *Love and kisses* means the writer is expressing her affection.

Answer (score 0):

The strictly correct grammatical use in your sentence is "mean".

> The invading armies mean war.
>   Trials by jury mean a fairer judicial system.
>   Ants mean you left some sweet residue on the counter.